# MYSQL set a session variable but it changes value before use in a SELECT

Tags: mysql, mariadb

I am setting a session variable, then using it in a SELECT statement as follows:

```
SET @balance = 14;
SELECT siuid,seq,impact, @balance := @balance + impact FROM 
( SELECT DISTINCT 12 AS siuid,'A' AS seq,-1 as impact       
  UNION    
  SELECT DISTINCT 13 AS siuid,'B' AS seq,-1 as impact       
) AS test
ORDER BY seq;
```

The results I get are:

```
siuid  seq  impact  @balance
12     A    -1      11
13     B    -1      10
```

Note that the first value of @balance is 11, not 13.

If I add SELECT @balance before the main SELECT, as follows...

```
SET @balance = 14;
SELECT  @balance;  /* <<< new line */
SELECT siuid,seq,impact, @balance := @balance + impact FROM 
( SELECT DISTINCT 12 AS siuid,'A' AS seq,-1 as impact       
  UNION    
  SELECT DISTINCT 13 AS siuid,'B' AS seq,-1 as impact       
) AS test
ORDER BY seq;
```

... the results are

```
siuid   seq impact  @balance    
12      A     -1    13
13      B     -1    12
```

This time @balance is what I would have expected.

I have observed that

> if I add another SELECT to the UNION, again with impact = -1, then the loss to @balance is now 3 cf the expected value
>
> if I then add another SELECT to the UNION, with impact = +5, then the @balance now gains 2 cf the expected value

Obviously the value of @balance is being modified by sum(impact) from the subquery, but why? and why would "SELECT @balance" stop it happening.

Can anyone tell me what is going on?

EDIT ===============
I changed the script to add "JOIN (SELECT @balance := 14) AS test2" to the outer select as @barmar suggested and it worked. I then played with it for a while, removing this and it still worked, but then my original script worked, and the script with the added "SELECT @balance" gave the wrong results. I played for a while and what seemed like a pattern when I posted the question originally was obviously quite unpredictable. In fact for the past 10 mins of flat out testing, I have not been able to get it to fail, regardless of which script variant I use.

I am sure sceptics out there will be thinking "what's he on", but it's a very simple exercise to change the script and hit Go - I really could not be the problem here.

I can only conclude that there was something else influencing my environment that I can't see. I have read other disparaging comments about phpMyAdmin - perhaps they were well grounded.

Comment: Are you sure this is happening? What mysql version do you use? How do you execute this? It looks like you just executed your query twice (or didn't start at the beginning again).

Comment: It is definitely happening. I an executing this in phpMyAdmin, which might be the problem. I am executing the entire script every time. I have tried closing phpMyAdmin and starting a fresh session. I can reproduce the behavior at will.

Comment: I can't reproduce this with MySQL 5.5.

Comment: Can't reproduce with 5.6 either.

Comment: I am using MySQL Version 10.0.25-MariaDB-cll-lve

Comment: What happens if you join with `(SELECT @balance := 14)` instead of doing it as a separate query?

Comment: I am on a hosted environment so don't have any control

Comment: MariaDB is like MySQL, but it's not the same.

Comment: Can't reproduce it either.

Comment: instead of setting the variable outside the query, consider cross joining to an inline view where you set it. ...`as test cross join (SELECT @balace := 14)...`

Comment: Thanks for your interest everyone. Please see my edit to the Question. The problem has, very unsatisfactorily, gone away, but in my mind is not resolved.